# Reverse column with bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a problem that I can't solve. I have this predisposition in my image and text files. In the mobile version, however, I would like to always keep the texts above the image, while in this way they alternate.
here my codepen:

https://codepen.io/edalbe/pen/BaGqGQb

```css
@media(max-width:991.98px) {
    .background_change{
        margin-top: 20rem;
    }
}

.panel.first-panel {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
.panel:not(.first-panel) {
      margin-top: 15rem;
}

.panel {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #151718;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
.panel .container{
        display: flex;
}

.color-white {
  background-color: #fff;
}
.color-yellow {
  background-color: #FBFD78;
}
.color-blue {
  background-color: #92C8FA;
}
.color-green {
  background-color: #4DA660;
}
.color-purple {
  background-color: #C4B9F9;
}
.panel .ri{
    position: relative; 
    right: -150px;
}
.panel .le{
    position: relative; 
    left: -150px;
}
@media(max-width:991.98px) {
    .panel .ri{
    right: 0px;
    }
    .panel .le{
    left: 0px;
    }
    .panel .container{
        display: block;
    }
  .panel {
  margin-top: 7rem;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: #151718;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
<section class="background_change">
  <div class="container mb-3" style="padding-top: 5rem;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel first-panel" data-color="white">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto text-left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-12 mx-auto text-center"> <img class="img-fluid ri" src="https://cdn.thecollector.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/napoleon-bonaparte-cossia-louise-david-paintings.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="yellow">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-12 mx-auto text-center"> <img class="img-fluid le" src="https://cdn.thecollector.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/napoleon-bonaparte-cossia-louise-david-paintings.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto text-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="blue">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto text-left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-12 mx-auto text-center"> <img class="img-fluid ri" src="https://cdn.thecollector.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/napoleon-bonaparte-cossia-louise-david-paintings.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="green">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-12 mx-auto text-center"> <img class="img-fluid le" src="https://cdn.thecollector.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/napoleon-bonaparte-cossia-louise-david-paintings.jpg"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto text-right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel" data-color="purple">
    <div class="container h-100">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-12 mx-auto text-left">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 col-12 mx-auto text-center"> <img class="img-fluid ri" src="https://cdn.thecollector.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/napoleon-bonaparte-cossia-louise-david-paintings.jpg"> </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

How could I solve it? (use bootstrap). Thanks to those who will help me

Comment: You could setup all of your panel divs to be _text then image_ so you get the look you want on small (i.e. mobile) devices (Bootstrap is _mobile first_), and then use [Bootstrap 4's order utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/flex/#order) to change the order on selected panels for larger (e.g. medium) displays.